# How do I show Modal Dialog after button is clicked and page is refreshed?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a modal dialog that shows when the user adds a product to cart..  I would like to display this "mini cart" dialog automatically when the "Update Cart" button is clicked in my modal dialog and I am not sure how to do it.

I am using Woocommerce and when the update cart button is clicked then the page refreshes (but doesnt show modal dialog automatically), I am wondering how I can execute this AFTER the update cart has been clicked and document has reloaded.

I have read to use a cookie and check the value and if set then display the modal, I also thought of the possibility of adding a hidden input within the cart form and finally tried appending a string at the end of the url after the page reload.  None of these were a success for me and I just dont know how I can execute JS after that button has been clicked and the page has been reloaded..

Here is what fires my modal dialog...

```
$('#shopModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

here is the javascript in its entirety **my problem is the dom reset after the page reloads so this never actually fires.  You will see my methods implemented here..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    if(window.location.href.indexOf("?added-to-cart=") > 0) {
       $('#shopModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    } 

    //after update cart has been clicked
    $('#update-cart').click(function() {
        //SetCookie('CartUpdated','yes',1);
            //ShowReveal();

        var $el = $('a[href*="/"]');
        $el.attr("href", $el.attr("href")+ "?added-to-cart=");
    });

    var updated_cart = $.cookie('CartUpdated');
    if(updated_cart == 'yes' {
        $('#shopModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    }

    function ShowReveal() {
        $('#shopModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    }

    function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
             var today = new Date();
             var expire = new Date();
            if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
             expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
             document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)+ ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
    }

    function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
           var theCookie=" "+document.cookie;
           var ind=theCookie.indexOf(" "+cookieName+"=");
           if (ind==-1) ind=theCookie.indexOf(";"+cookieName+"=");
           if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return "";
           var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(";",ind+1);
           if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
        return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+2,ind1));
      }

    });

});
</script>
```

And here is the shortened form

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">

                <input id="update-cart" type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php _e( 'Update Cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> 


</form>
```

**Would it be better to try and apply a string like ?added-to-cart= to the url after page reload, better to set a cookie and check its value then execute or is there something I could do with a hidden input field? I tried all of these but cannot find out why it is not working?**

Comment: If the page is refreshed, you'd have to do this on the new page. *"Would it be better to try and apply a string like ?added-to-cart= to the url after page reload, better to set a cookie and check its value then execute"* something like that would work, yes.

Comment: Where am I going wrong then?  I tried this:

'$('#update-cart').click(function() {
  //SetCookie('CartUpdated','yes',1);
   //ShowReveal();
   
  var $el = $('a[href*="/"]');
        $el.attr("href", $el.attr("href")+ "?added-to-cart=");
 });'

but doesnt work, or atleast it doesnt stick after the page has reloaded :(

Comment: on load of the new page, are you checking the url for said value and then opening the popup?

Comment: @KevinB I can do that no problem, the problem is appending the '?added-to-cart=' string to the url, any suggestions?

Comment: what *exactly* is causing you to go to the new page?

Comment: Ok, lets say I am on the single product page and click add to cart button, then the page automatically refreshes and when it does it adds the string '?added-to-cart=' to the url in the browser.  Because of this the modal shows automatically (refer to the first function in above javascript).  When on a regular page and you click my cart button to show the modal dialog (which displays the cart) and I change the quantity of one of the products in my cart and click the above update cart, the page refreshes but string never gets appended to the url. My question is to how to add that to url?

Comment: what exactly is the add to cart button? is it literally a button, thus causing the form to submit, which causes the navigation?

Comment: Looks like all you're going to have to do is change the action attribute of the form.

Comment: Not sure what to change it to though.. I am not to familiar with forms and actions enough to know a good solution.  Could you provide an example?  Just need something that checks to see if the url already contains ?added-to-cart= and if it doesnt then append that to the url on form submit.  Thought I was close but I guess not :/